# How many numbers for the full joint?

Tags: probability, bayesian

Suppose you have 3 binary nodes A, B, C.  A and B are independent given C.

How many numbers do we need for the full joint?

How many numbers do we need for the Baysesian Net?

I know the answers to both of these questions because they are given (7 and 5 respectively) But I do not know where these answers came from or what they actually mean.  If someone could explain that, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Could you define some of these terms?  In this context, what is a "binary node", "full joint", and "Bayesian Net"?  What does it mean for two nodes to be independent given a third?

Comment: Binary node means there are only 2 options, true and false... Full joint and Bayesian net I am not sure.

Comment: If you're not sure what the definitions are, how do you expect to be able to solve the problem?  Sounds like you have the answers, so presumably you're using a textbook.  That book should also have the relevant definitions.

Answer (score 0):

We have $C$ being the parent of both $A$ and $B$, so we have the following probability factorisation:

$$P(A,B,C) = P(A\mid C)P(B\mid C)P(C).$$

To specify the full joint probability distribution with $3$ binary nodes (i.e. random variables), you need to list all $2^3 = 8$ possible combinations and give each a probability - these are the "numbers" you refer to. Since these $8$ probabilities must sum to $1$, you can deduce the eighth one from the rest so, in fact, we need to specify only $7$ probabilities.

However, if you use the factorised version (RHS of above equation), then:

- You need to specify $2^1 - 1 = 1$ probability for $P(C)$, by the same argument as above.
- For $P(A\mid C)$ you must specify two probabilities: $P(A\mid C)$ and $P(A\mid \neg C)$, from which you can deduce $P(\neg A\mid C) = 1 - P(A\mid C)$ and $P(\neg A\mid \neg C) = 1 - P(A\mid \neg C)$ as before. So that's $2$ probabilities.
- $P(B\mid C)$ is the same so that's a further $2$ probabilities.

In total we have $1+2+2=5$ probabilities needed.